# Path planning for robot car on grid

Tags: python, path-planning, opencv, autonomous-car, dynamic-programming

I am currently doing a project as my hobby. I am trying to simulate a robot car in a grid arena.      Below is the image of the arena:

[image]

The start point of the car is the bottom-right corner(dark green box). And I have to reach at pink grid using the shortest path possible. Shortest path in the sense that cost of crossing the grid. The weights/costs of grids are as follows:
Red:4, Yellow:3, Green:2, White:1. Black grids are block/walls.

**My implementation:**

I used the OpenCV library in python to segment the colors of the grid and finding the centroids for each grid. centroid matrix is as follows:

```
[[( 34,  34) ( 85,  34) (137,  34) (  0,   0) (240,  34) (292,  34)]
 [( 34,  85) (  0,   0) (137,  85) (  0,   0) (240,  85) (291,  85)]
 [( 34, 137) ( 85, 137) (137, 137) (188, 137) (240, 137) (291, 137)]
 [(  0,   0) ( 86, 191) (137, 188) (188, 188) (  0,   0) (291, 188)]
 [( 34, 240) ( 85, 240) (137, 240) (  0,   0) (  0,   0) (291, 240)]
 [( 34, 292) (  0,   0) (137, 291) (188, 291) (240, 291) (291, 291)]]
```

Then I created an adjacency matrix(36*36) based on the nodes connected. Below is the adjacency matrix in form of a list:

```
[[0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 4 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 0]]
```

Then I have implemented the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path as:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Graph:
    def minDistance(self,dist,queue):
        minimum = float("Inf")
        min_index = -1
        for i in range(len(dist)):
            if dist[i] < minimum and i in queue:
                minimum = dist[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index
def printPath(self, parent, j):
    if parent[j] == -1 : 
        print (j)
        return
    self.printPath(parent , parent[j])
    print(j)
def printSolution(self, dist, parent):
    src = 0
    print("Vertex \t\tDistance from Source\tPath")
    for i in range(1, len(dist)):
        print("\n%d --> %d \t\t%d \t\t\t\t\t" % (src, i, dist[i])),
        self.printPath(parent,i)
def dijkstra(self, graph, src):

    row = len(graph)
    col = len(graph[0])
    dist = [float("Inf")] * row
    parent = [-1] * row
    dist[src] = 0
    queue = []
    for i in range(row):
        queue.append(i)
    while queue:
        u = self.minDistance(dist,queue)  
        queue.remove(u)
    for i in range(col):
        if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
            if dist[u] + graph[u][i] < dist[i]:
                dist[i] = dist[u] + graph[u][i]
                parent[i] = u
    self.printSolution(dist,parent)
```

However, this code is raising an error on executing as:

```
g= Graph()
g.dijkstra(graph,35) #src at node 35
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-166-4785fe512432> in <module>
      1 g= Graph()
      2 graph = adj
----> 3 g.dijkstra(graph,35)

<ipython-input-146-4fd492228481> in dijkstra(self, graph, src)
     86 
     87             # remove min element
---> 88             queue.remove(u)
     89 
     90             # Update dist value and parent

 ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The output should be like this:

```
 Vertex           Distance         Path 
 0 -> 2          12        0 1 2
```

**My doubts/questions:**

**1)** Am I implementing/proceeding rightly to help the car reach its destination? Are these ideas good or I should choose a different approach? If yes, please suggest.

**2)** How can I resolve the issue in my code? I don't know why I am getting this error. If I should use a different algorithm/approach, please sugget.

**3)** Is my adjacency matrix right? I made it based on 36 connecting nodes with weights.

I am not a computer science student but doing it because of my interest. I have got no guide/teacher to teach me these things and looking at this site to resolve my issues.
I request you to please provide guidance.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have time to do a full code review here, but the short version of why you're getting the error is that, as the error states, you're trying to remove an element from `queue` that either wasn't added or was already removed.

I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing, so I would highly suggest you attach a debugger and step through your code and watch it operate. For example:

```
def minDistance(self,dist,queue):
    minimum = float("Inf")
    min_index = -1
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        if dist[i] < minimum and i in queue:
            minimum = dist[i]
            min_index = i
    return min_index
```

You're comparing all the entries in `dist` to `float("Inf")`, but what is `dist`? That's defined in the calling function:

```
def dijkstra(self, graph, src):

    dist = [float("Inf")] * row
```

So if every element in `dist` is `float("Inf")`, then will there ever be an element in `dist` that is less than `float("Inf")`? No. So what happens then, if your distance entries aren't less than `Inf`? You will still

```
return min_index
```

where `min_index` is initialized to `-1`.

The summary on what I think is going wrong here is this:

1. You build a queue of all rows, then
2. You check the distance on each row, then
3. If that distance fails your check, you are returning -1 as the index, then
4. You are not checking the index on the returned variable, you're instead just blindly removing that index from queue, then
5. Because queue is a vector of row numbers and -1 is not a row number, you get an exception when you try to remove -1 from your queue.

The part that I don't have time to get into here is your *intent*. Why are you trying to do with your code? You are running

```
while queue:
    u = self.minDistance(dist,queue)  
    queue.remove(u)
```

This will remove all the entries in your queue until `queue` is null/empty, but as mentioned above `self.minDistance` will return -1 unless the `dist[i] < minimum and i in queue`.

I can't tell what your intent is, but I *think* maybe you should just be calling `u = self.minDistance` once and not repeatedly. This hunch seems to be further confirmed by looking a few lines down in your code:

```
while queue:
    u = self.minDistance(dist,queue)  
    queue.remove(u)
for i in range(col):
    if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
```

If you are running `queue.remove(u)` until `queue` becomes empty/null, then how does it exist later when you check `if graph[u][i] and i in queue`?

I would guess instead of:

```
for i in range(row):
    queue.append(i)
while queue:
    u = self.minDistance(dist,queue)  
    queue.remove(u)
for i in range(col):
    if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
```

would you would want

```
for i in range(row):
    queue.append(i)
u = self.minDistance(dist,queue)  
for i in range(col):
    if graph[u][i] and i in queue:
```

but I'm not a python user and haven't looked more at your algorithm.

At a minimum, though, if you are going to do `queue.remove(u)` then you need to check if `queue` **contains** `u` first. If it doesn't then print yourself a nice warning and I'd bet that'll reveal your issue.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer. I thought removing 'u' from the queue and saving it to the parent list might work. Cause once I have included that node in the path of the car, it's not necessary to iterate on it('u') again to get the new nodes with a minimum distance of current node. However, I will implement your advice to resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @UjjawalM. - As I stated in the post, I haven't looked hard at your methods beyond the particular error, so I could be wrong here with my guidance, but it looks like you're iterating through all the entries in `dist` in the `minDistance` function, so I'm not sure what is going to happen on subsequent calls that would get you lower distances. You don't appear to be recalculating anything that I can see; you just remove an entry from `queue` and do the same thing over again. Hope this helps!